# Entity Framework + SqlQuery<T> - What is the purpose of this code (NerdDinner)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was looking at the NerdDinner code on codeplex and noticed the following:

```
public IQueryable<Dinner> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
{
    List<Dinner> resultList = new List<Dinner>();

    var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Dinner>("SELECT * FROM Dinners WHERE EventDate >= {0} AND dbo.DistanceBetween({1}, {2}, Latitude, Longitude) < 1000", DateTime.Now, latitude, longitude);
    foreach (Dinner result in results)
    {
        resultList.Add(db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == result.DinnerID).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    return resultList.AsQueryable<Dinner>();
}
```

I'm curious what the point of this line is:

```
resultList.Add(db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == result.DinnerID).FirstOrDefault();
```

The code is calling ExecuteQuery to retrieve the Dinners. Why is there a need to query again calling FirstOrDefault() to add to the list?

Comment: What's the type of 'results'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the `SqlQuery`:

*The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(VS.103).aspx

The provided code seems then to be the workaround for converting the set of objects that are not tracked to objects that are tracked by the framework.

Comment: I learned smthg here. I would rather call db.Dinners.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == result.DinnerID); though